# How does MongoDB text search work?

Tags: mongodb

I create new collection called test_index and insert two documents:

```
var mydocs = [

{t: "Her", language: "english"},
{t: "El asaltante", language: "spanish"}

]

db.test_index.insert(mydocs)
```

Create text index for `t` field:

```
db.test_index.ensureIndex({"t": "text"})
```

Make a search:

```
db.test_index.find({$text: {$search: "asaltante"}})
```

No results are returned.

Instead, if I use $text as follows it works.

```
db.test_index.find({$text: {$search: "asaltante", $language: "spanish"}})
```

Is that the intended use? Should I make 10 $text searches if I have 10 translations. It sounds like inefficient. How does MongoDB $text $search work?

Comment: I believe its because of `'language'` field in your document. rename it and your query should be working fine

Comment: @Disposer According to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/, 'language' should be defined to override default (English).

Comment: I can reproduce this. It does work when `language` isn't set (defaulting to English), or when the language is set explicitly to English or German. Looks like `asaltante` is explicitly ignored for Spanish text - searching for `corazon` in `this is really asaltante, corazon` worked, for instance, but searching for `asaltante` still doesn't find that particular document. Looks like a bug in the stopwords, unless `asaltante` is an extremely common word and should indeed be on the stopword list. I doubt it from what a google translate tells me... ("raider")

Comment: This makes no sense. I've tried with "asaltante", "mesías", "cazafantasmas" and none of the searches return results. None of them are Spanish stop words. With "corazón" and "rompecorazones" it does return results. Very weird :-/

Comment: I'm not reproducing the results here even though it looks like multiple people are. Can someone post a shell script or the exact seuqence of commands to reproduce this, along with the MongoDB version they are using? I am trying on 2.6.4.

Comment: @wdberkeley https://gist.github.com/bgvo/bb9ac76968cad1c4eddd

Comment: Ok, I get the same results as the gist, but that looks like it's working fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it find the second document? Correct me if I'm wrong. I thought that once you specify language inside each subdocument, you don't have to specify it when calling $text. Isn't there a way to make just one search and it searches over all documents according to rules specified for each language (stop-words, stemming)?