# Full Text Search taking too long

Tags: mongodb

My database has 2583000 documents so far. It is static (we don't insert new documents often).

This is a sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5492d118426f72116a436a0c"),
    "dst" : "string",
    "n" : "All the Light We Cannot See",
    "su" : "some string...",
    "detail" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("982736408170649823746"),
        "au" : [ 
            "string"
        ],
        "auu" : [ 
            "some string..."
        ],
        "be" : null,
        "bf" : "some string...",
        "bp" : 531,
        "ch" : [],
        "ela" : "English",
        "fp" : null,
        "g" : [ 
            "Historical Fiction", 
            "Fiction", 
            "Book Club", 
            "History", 
            "World War II", 
            "War", 
            "Cultural", 
            "France", 
            "Adult", 
            "Adult Fiction", 
            "Literary Fiction", 
            "Cultural", 
            "Germany"
        ],
        "i13" : "some string...",
        "ior" : "some string...",
        "isb" : "some string...",
        "ism" : "some string...",
        "ist" : "some string...",
        "k" : "book",
        "law" : [ 
            "some string here"
        ],
        "oec" : 17,
        "oeu" : "some string",
        "ot" : "All The Light We Cannot See",
        "ott" : {
            "English" : "All the Light We Cannot See",
            "German" : "Alles Licht, das wir nicht sehen"
        },
        "pu" : "Published May 6th 2014 by Scribner",
        "r" : 4.18,
        "rc" : 27738,
        "rvc" : 4220,
        "stt" : [ 
            "Paris"
        ],
        "sy" : "sime text here...",
        "tad" : null,
        "tau" : null,
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-11-03T11:36:15.436Z")
    },
    "sv" : "1",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-12-18T13:05:28.190Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-12-18T13:05:28.190Z")
}
```

The "text" index I have set:

```
db.items.ensureIndex(

{"n": "text", "detail.est" : "text", "detail.ot" : "text"}, {default_language: "none"}

)
```

Note that not all fields used at the time of index creation are in all the documents. Also, I've used `default_language : none` as I text_search through different languages at the same time.

Some days ago I had half the documents I have now and Search was fast. Now, following results seem very strange to me and there is something I don't quite understand:

**AND Search**

- Time: 138 seconds
- Query: db.items.find({$text: {$search: "\"all\" \"the\" \"light\" \"we\" \"cannot\" \"see\""}})

Explain:

```
{
    "cursor" : "TextCursor",
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 720806,
    "nscanned" : 733110,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 720806,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 733110,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "nYields" : 13395,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 161997,
    "server" : "myserver.com",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "TEXT",
        "works" : 1453924,
        "yields" : 13395,
        "unyields" : 13395,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 2,
        "needTime" : 1453921,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "keysExamined" : 733110,
        "fetches" : 720806,
        "parsedTextQuery" : {
            "terms" : [ 
                "all", 
                "the", 
                "light", 
                "we", 
                "cannot", 
                "see"
            ],
            "negatedTerms" : [],
            "phrases" : [ 
                "all", 
                "the", 
                "light", 
                "we", 
                "cannot", 
                "see"
            ],
            "negatedPhrases" : []
        },
        "children" : []
    }
}
```

**OR Search**

- Time: 4.4 seconds
- Query: db.items.find({$text: {$search: "all the light we cannot see"}})

Explain:

```
{
    "cursor" : "TextCursor",
    "n" : 720806,
    "nscannedObjects" : 720806,
    "nscanned" : 733110,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 720806,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 733110,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "nYields" : 12317,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 127775,
    "server" : "myserver.com",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "TEXT",
        "works" : 1453924,
        "yields" : 12317,
        "unyields" : 12317,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 720806,
        "needTime" : 733117,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "keysExamined" : 733110,
        "fetches" : 720806,
        "parsedTextQuery" : {
            "terms" : [ 
                "all", 
                "the", 
                "light", 
                "we", 
                "cannot", 
                "see"
            ],
            "negatedTerms" : [],
            "phrases" : [],
            "negatedPhrases" : []
        },
        "children" : []
    }
}
```

**Exact Search**

- Time: 0.06 seconds
- Query: db.items.find({"n": "All the Light We Cannot See"})

Explain:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor n_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 2583249,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2583249,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 20183,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 9056,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "n" : [ 
            [ 
                "", 
                {}
            ], 
            [ 
                /All the Light We Cannot See/i, 
                /All the Light We Cannot See/i
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "myserver.com",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "FETCH",
        "works" : 2583250,
        "yields" : 20183,
        "unyields" : 20183,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 2,
        "needTime" : 2583247,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "forcedFetches" : 0,
        "matchTested" : 0,
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                "works" : 2583249,
                "yields" : 20183,
                "unyields" : 20183,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 2,
                "needTime" : 2583247,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : "{ n: 1.0 }",
                "isMultiKey" : 0,
                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['n']: [\"\", {}), [/All the Light We Cannot See/i, /All the Light We Cannot See/i]",
                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 2,
                "keysExamined" : 2583249,
                "children" : []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Regexp Search**

- Time: 9.64 seconds
- Query: db.items.find({"n": /All the Light We Cannot See/i})

Explain:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor n_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 2583249,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2583249,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 20183,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 9056,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "n" : [ 
            [ 
                "", 
                {}
            ], 
            [ 
                /All the Light We Cannot See/i, 
                /All the Light We Cannot See/i
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "myserver.com0",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "FETCH",
        "works" : 2583250,
        "yields" : 20183,
        "unyields" : 20183,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 2,
        "needTime" : 2583247,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "forcedFetches" : 0,
        "matchTested" : 0,
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                "works" : 2583249,
                "yields" : 20183,
                "unyields" : 20183,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 2,
                "needTime" : 2583247,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : "{ n: 1.0 }",
                "isMultiKey" : 0,
                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['n']: [\"\", {}), [/All the Light We Cannot See/i, /All the Light We Cannot See/i]",
                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 2,
                "keysExamined" : 2583249,
                "children" : []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice that the exact result search is the fastest one. What I don't understand is why AND search takes so much more time if the fields involved in the search are indexed. My guesses are that MongoDB Text Index is not optimized for AND and in its simplest expression (OR search) it is much slower than regular-single field index.

Two questions here:

- Is there any way to improve these searches using Mongodb Text Search?
- Can I be missing something at the time of creating the index, so that Text Search is not performing as desired?

Comment: Have you tried [explaining the queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to compare the chosen query plans and efficiency? Text search will be looking through a much larger index than a simple find. A case-insensitive regex will (at best) be scanning all of the index keys. I also notice you have chosen a `default_language` of none, which disables stemming and stopwords. That means your text index may be bloated with some extremely common words like "the" and "and". It looks like you all the text you are indexing is English?

Comment: It would also be helpful to describe your use case requirements (i.e. search functionality you need to provide, rather than only how you are trying to search).

Comment: @stennie, I search for Spanish as well. I've updated the question posting each query explanation.

Comment: Please drop the index, recreate it with a default language of English and try again. I assume it takes as long because MongoDB applies stemming and stop words for all languages it knows.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg, but I have some titles, as "Her", which are not indexed if I set default language to English. The solution I came up with was to establish "none" as default, but as you said, it seems to add too much overhead. In addition, I need to search for Spanish titles as well. What would it be a good solution for this in your opinion? Thanks!

Comment: @borjagvo You can include a `language` field in your docs and sub-docs to override the `default_language` of the index.  So for "Her" you could set a language of "none", and for the Spanish docs (or sub-docs) use a language of "spanish". Docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/#create-a-text-index-for-a-collection-in-multiple-languages).

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK, however, I made a question just about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381041/how-does-mongodb-text-search-work. Is there a way of searching through all documents in its respective languages without changing the $language operator?

Comment: @borjagvo: I'd suggest an iterative approach. First, let's get rid of those ridiculous performance issues (pun intended). Unless we have solved these, the system is close to useless anyway. But: using a different language without telling MongoDB to do so would be a bit of black magic, don't you think.